# How to make unwanted white space shrink in webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, dynamic

I have a page contains two vertically divs. First div contains iframe holder and the second random contents. The iframe can be less or more in height (has dynamic height).

The problem when the iframe holder decrease in height, that causes unwanted **white space** between the iframe holder and the second div below it. This problem occurs in **chrome** only, IE & FF are working fine.

How can I make this white space **shrinks** when the iframe decrease in height?

**[Here is my page](http://minvox.com/dedicated-servers/)**

The iframe holder div contains the menu tabs, the second div below it contains a 3 columns of contents.

---

**Update #1:**

Screenshot one:

[image]

Screenshot two:

[image]

Comment: How can we see the problem??? your page works fine for me in chrome

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Danko I will post an update with screenshots now.

Comment: @Danko I added screenshots now, let me know if you have any suggestions please. Thank you..

Comment: why not use your js to grow the bottom div to he remainder size of the viewport

Answer (score 1):

If you add jQuery to dual_core.html then the following script should help. You can do the equivalent without jQuery, but I had something similar made so I just replaced with your selector IDs.

```
$('#dualcore_servers_menu_wrapper1 a').click(function(){
    menuHeight = $('#dualcore_servers_menu_wrapper1').height();
    contentHeight = $('#dualcore_servers_content_wrapper1').height();
    $('iframe[name="dservers"]').height( (menuHeight + contentHeight) + 'px');
});
```

Its not exact, the $('iframe[name="dservers"]') selector will need to change, but its the general idea.
Hope this helps!

Comment: I added height="auto" in my iframe code but still not working in chrome. it works only in IE & FF.

Comment: I can't implement it correctly. I attached the "jquery-1.10.2.min.js " within the page, copied and pasted your code between these tags <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script> but it didn't work. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Try what I posted on your other question. If it works I will update the answer here. :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your `<iframe>` is being given an inline `height` of `311px;`

My guess would be that it's getting the height of the largest tab and applying it them all with this js:

```
function resizeIframe(obj) {
    obj.style.height = obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
  }
```

and or

```
onload='javascript:resizeIframe(this);'
```

Comment: So, is there anyway to make the js auto adjust height? Thank you for your help.