# How to auto shrink iframe height dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I use the following code to achieve **dynamic iframe** height:

In the `<head>`:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function resizeIframe(obj) {
obj.style.height = obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
}
</script>
```

In the `<body>`:

```
<iframe name="myiframe" src="somepage.html" width="100%" frameborder="0"
scrolling="no" onload='javascript:resizeIframe(this);' />
</iframe>
```

This codes works fine with height increasing only. So, when the content inside the iframe increases in height, the iframe updates its height and increases with it.

The problem is  with height **decreasing** or **shrinking**. When the content inside the iframe decreases, it doesn't decrease and causing big unwanted white space. This only occurs in **Chrome**, IE & FF works fine.

**[Here is my Page](http://minvox.com/dedicated-servers/)**

I want to know how to make this code works to auto shrink iframe height when it decreases?

**Screenshot one:**

[image: Screenshot one]

**Screenshot two:**

[image: Screenshot two]

---

**Update 1**

I placed the following code in the `<head>`

```
<script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
var iframeDoc = $('iframe[name="dservers"]').contents().get(0);
$('iframe[name="dservers"]').load(function(){
    docHeight = $(iframeDoc).height();
    $('iframe[name="dservers"]').height( docHeight );
});
});
```

The iframe code in the `<body>`

```
<iframe name="dservers" src="dual_core.html" width="100%" frameborder="0"
scrolling="no" /></iframe>
```

The iframe not showing in the page. It appears for one second and then disappears.

---

**Update 2**

I think The problem was the `$` character before `(function(){`, I removed it. I'm sorry I don't have much experience with jquery. I updated the page and removed the `onload="resizeFrame()"` but the iframe doesn't act dynamically now.

Comment: Duplicate [Your previous of the same question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20495933/how-to-make-unwanted-white-space-shrink-in-webpage/20496181#20496181) This solution will work for you if you implement it correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Problem Solved**

I was digging in the internet and I found a code solved the whole problem for me. I would like to share it so anyone can use it in order to get dynamic iframe height.

**First**, put the following code between the `<head>` tags:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function getDocHeight(doc) {
doc = doc || document;
var body = doc.body, html = doc.documentElement;
var height = Math.max( body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight );
return height;
}
function setIframeHeight(myiframeid) {
var ifrm = document.getElementById(myiframeid);
var doc = ifrm.contentDocument? ifrm.contentDocument: ifrm.contentWindow.document;
ifrm.style.visibility = 'hidden';
ifrm.style.height = "10px";
ifrm.style.height = getDocHeight( doc ) + 5+"px";
ifrm.style.visibility = 'visible';
}
</script>
<script>(function(run){
for (i=0;i<frames.length; i++) {
var f1 = document.getElementsByTagName('myiframename')[i];
if(!f1 && window.addEventListener && !run){
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', arguments.callee, false);
return;
}
if(!f1){setTimeout(arguments.callee, 300); return;}
f2 = f1.cloneNode(false);
f1.src = 'about: blank';
f2.frameBorder = '0';
f2.allowTransparency = 'yes';
f2.scrolling = 'no';
f1.parentNode.replaceChild(f2, f1);
}
})();
</script>
```

**Second**, the Iframe code in the `<body>` :

```
<iframe id="myiframeid" name="myiframename" src="somepage.html" width="100%"
frameborder="0" scrolling="no" onload='javascript:setIframeHeight(this.id);' />
</iframe>
```

**Third** and Last, the CSS:

```
#myiframeid{
width: 100%;
}
```

**Note:** You should have **Name** and **ID** for the Iframe.

Compatible with all browsers (**Chrome**, **Firefox**, **IE**).

Have a good day!

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a little library that deals with all these issues and keeps the iframed sized when the content changes or the browser window is resized.

https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer

Comment: Thanks for you library. In the demo page when I resize the window faster then the iframe height is not correctly getting adjusted. If I resize slow then it does. Any clue?

Comment: @VJAI not seen that before. Can you raise a ticket on github.

Answer (score 1):

I thought about it quite a bit, and think I came up with another solution that may resolve your problem from the parent document. Rather than editing the documents in your iframe. However I can't test it due to cross origin policy. Try this out and let me know how it works.

```
var iframeDoc = $('iframe[name="dservers"]').contents().get(0);
$('iframe[name="dservers"]').load(function(){
    docHeight = $(iframeDoc).height();
    $('iframe[name="dservers"]').height( docHeight );
});
```

Hope this does it for you.

Edit: This fix would require you to remove the onload="" function.

Edit-2: You seem to have combined the two scripts. You have this:

```
  function resizeIframe(obj) {
    obj.style.height = obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
    var iframeDoc = $('iframe[name="dservers"]').contents().get(0);
$('iframe[name="dservers"]').load(function(){
    docHeight = $(iframeDoc).height();
    $('iframe[name="dservers"]').height( docHeight );
});
  }
```

Replace that entire script with this:

```
$(function(){
    var iframeDoc = $('iframe[name="dservers"]').contents().get(0);
    $('iframe[name="dservers"]').load(function(){
        docHeight = $(iframeDoc).height();
        $('iframe[name="dservers"]').height( docHeight );
    });
});
```

And remove the onload="resizeFrame()" from the iframes tag.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm gonna try this now and come back with the result.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work. I'm not sure if I'm implementing it in a right way, but I attached the "jquery-1.10.2.min.js" in the parent page, copied and pasted your code between the following tags <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> in the head and another time I put the code within the iframe code itself in the body, tested both but didn't work.

Comment: Actually it also cancel the dynamic height.

Comment: Hi again, it seems that I was inserting the code wrong. I'm sorry I was very tired. But it 100% works well now. Thank you very much for your help, I appreciate it.

Comment: Not a problem! Glad to help :)

Comment: The problem just fixed in chrome and appeared again but in **firefox**. It rather works on chrome or firefox, please see the [**page**](http://minvox.com/dedicated-servers/) and let me know if you have any solution to work on both browsers. (IE is working fine). Thank you in advance.

Comment: Edited the answer. That should hopefully fix your problem.

Comment: I inserted your code, the iframe appears for one second and then disappears. I left the code as it is in the page so that you can take a look on it. I also updated the question (update1). Thank you very much.

Comment: I think The problem was the `$` character before `(function(){`, I removed it. I'm sorry I'm not have much experience with jquery. I updated the page and removed the onload="resizeFrame()" but the iframe doesn't act dynamically.

Comment: I found nice code and it solved the problem. I posted it as an answer, please take a look on it. Thanks..